# CakePHP how validate radio buttons?

Tags: php, cakephp, validation

How to validate CakePHP radio buttons?

Doesn't work inList rule and notEmpty...

$this->data return good content

Comment: You need to show more code, at least the validation rule and preferably the part of the form where you create the radio buttons.

Answer (score 5):

As @Juhana mentioned in the comments, it's helpful if you're more specific.

Typically, however, something like this should work:

In your model:

```
var $validate = array(
    'radioField' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
     )
);
```

In your view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('radioField', array(
    'type' => 'radio', 
    'options' => array('foo', 'bar')
    )
);
```

*Alternatively* you can use the [radio-specific](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#radio) method in your view:

```
echo $this->Form->radio('radioField', array('foo', 'bar'));
```

But then you must include the following line in order to display the error:

```
echo $this->Form->error('radioField');
```